# How to create an outline (with controllable thickness) from a mask segmentation image in Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

[image: Mask Image]

Here I have an image for a segmentation output from one of the segmentation models. 
I would like to create an outline for these masks and then put that outline on the original image to indicate the predicted areas on the image as segmentation output.

I tried using PIL filter FIND_EDGES but it gives very thin edges for an outline.

Is there any way to convert this mask image into an image with just outlines for these masks where I can control the thickness of the outline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to find the outline of all the blobs then draw this outline onto another image with controllable outline thickness. You can do this using [`cv2.drawContours()`](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/06/hi-this-article-is-tutorial-which-try.html) and control the outline thickness using the `thickness` parameter. Setting a negative value eg. `-1`, will fill in the contour while increasing the parameter will give you a thicker outline.

In this example, we find the contours of each blob using `cv2.findContours()` then draw the outline onto a mask using `cv2.drawContours()`. In your case, instead of drawing it onto a mask, you can draw it onto your desired image. With `thickness=2`:

[image]

With `thickness=5`:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
mask = np.ones(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8) * 255
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cnts = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (36, 255, 12), thickness=5)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I wanted. I will try it and let you know!